# Cannot modify value nor placeholder of HTML forms

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6

I'm building this app with react, when pass the actual value like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input 
       value={this.state.setupList[0]} onChange{this.handleChange}
       name="date" class="form-control"  placeholder={this.state.setupList[0]} />
</div>
```

I can see the text but no modifications allowed, that's the function I'm using for the form:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

Please someone suggest a better approach to fix the issue

Structure of the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    setupList: [],
    title: '',
    description: '',
    show: false,
  };
}
```

A random function I found on internet to store input in a value

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

With that I update the db

```
updateData = e => {
    this.setState({ loading: true})
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    e.preventDefault();
    let title = this.state.title;
    let description = this.state.description;
    fire.database().ref(`/master/${currentUser.uid}/setup/`)
    .update({
      title: this.state.title,
      description: this.state.description,
    })
    .then(() => {
    this.setState({ loading: false, show:false})
  });
}
```

And probably the issue is here

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  fire.database().ref(`/master/${currentUser.uid}/setup/`)
  .on('value', snapshot => {
  var obj = snapshot.val()
  var setupList = []
  var keys = []
  for(let a in obj){
      setupList.push(obj[a])
      keys.push(a)
  }
   this.setState({
  setupList:setupList,
  keys:keys,

  ...
```

Comment: because you updating the value in `date` state variable and with value attribute using `this.state.setupList[0]}`. Solution is either use `value={this.state.date  || ''}` or update `this.state.setupList[0]`. If you want to show the initial value from `this.state.setupList[0]` then write it like this: `value={this.state.date || this.state.setupList[0]}`

Comment: please provide your state structure

Comment: @mayank-shukla this not working

Comment: @blvckasvp it should work, can you show your full code? are you getting any error?

Comment: @nguyễn-thanh-tú updated the question

Comment: please also provide the structure of the `obj` object in this statement `var obj = snapshot.val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `value` to `defaultValue` works as expected. Such an easy solution

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input 
       defaultValue={this.state.setupList[0]} onChange{this.handleChange}
       name="date" class="form-control" placeholder={this.state.setupList[0]} />
</div>
```